# rpart not running when trying to create classication tree

Tags: r, classification, r-caret, rpart

When using the following on my dataset, I am getting an error message.

```
rpmodel <- train(Class~.,train, method = "rpart", prox = TRUE)


Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:
    Accuracy       Kappa    
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :3     NA's   :3    
Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : Stopping
In addition: There were 26 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

However there are no `NA` in the dataset.

Comment: What say the warnings?

Comment: @XavierNayrac I've posted the warning which is being shown

Comment: Please post the warnings. You will see them by typing `warnings()`.

Comment: Warning messages:
1: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
  model fit failed for Resample01: cp=0.01149 Error in rpart(formula = .outcome ~ ., data = structure(list(age = c(37,  : 
  Argument prox not matched

2: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
  model fit failed for Resample02: cp=0.01149 Error in rpart(formula = .outcome ~ ., data = structure(list(age = c(38,  : 
  Argument prox not matched

3: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
  model fit failed for Resample03: cp=0.01149 Error in rpart(formula = .outcome ~ ., data = structure(list(age = c(51,  :

Comment: Added some warnings only due to the word limit on stackoverflow

Comment: What are the variables classes? You can see them with `sapply(train, class)`

Answer (score 1):

The warnings tell you the problem. You are passing an argument (`prox`) that is neither an argument to `train` or `rpart`:

```
> "prox"  %in% names(formals(rpart))
[1] FALSE
> "prox"  %in% names(formals(train.formula))
[1] FALSE
```

Max

Answer (score 0):

You probably filtered one or more factor variables. Try to refactor them, because the factor levels are still available. See also [this issue](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/160) on github.

```
sapply(train, class)
# refactor all variables with class factor
variable <- factor(as.character(variable)
```

Comment: Thank you I will try it @phiver